# c# closures lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

Could any one explain what is going on in the below code? Why is nothing getting printed?

```
var actions = new Action[100];
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    actions[i] = () => DoSomething(i);
}

foreach(var action in actions)
{
    action();
}

void DoSomething(int i)
{
    if(i % 9 == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is a multiple of 9",i);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Classical *Closure and captured variables* problem. Change your loop as

```
 for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
 {
     int j = i;
     actions[i] = () => DoSomething(j);
 }
```

For more info: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter5/closures.aspx